# Create ItemRenderer extended from @Embed(source="xxx.png")ItemRenderer

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, charts, flex4, itemrenderer

Follow the question [last question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17403105/can-i-use-multiple-itemrenderer-with-one-lineseries/17419374#17419374)

I can successfully create the class extended from `CircleItemRenderer` or any other `ProgrammaticSkin` ItemRenderers like below.

```
public class LSLabelCircleItemRenderer extends CircleItemRenderer
    {
        private var _label:Label;
        public function LSLabelCircleItemRenderer():void
        {
            super();
            _label = new Label();
        }
        override protected function updateDisplayList(unscaledWidth:Number,unscaledHeight:Number):void
        {
            super.updateDisplayList(unscaledWidth, unscaledHeight);
            if(data != null){
                var ls:LineSeries = ChartItem(data).element as LineSeries;
                label.text = LineSeriesItem(data).yValue.toString();
                skin.parent.addChild(label);
                label.setStyle("color",ls.getStyle("fill"));
                label.move(skin.x - label.getExplicitOrMeasuredWidth() / 5,skin.y - label.getExplicitOrMeasuredHeight());
            }
        }       
    }
```

Now I found I find no where to do the same thing embedded-image ItemRenderer which in mxml is like below

```
itemRenderer="@Embed(source='../assets/butterfly.gif')"
```

How do I add my custome label with this kind of `ItemRenderer`?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Similar how you did the previous itemRenderer, you can add the embedded image to the extended itemRenderer

```
[Embed(source="../assets/butterfly.gif")][Bindable] public var butterflyClass:Class;

var image:Image = new Image();
image.source =  butterflyClass;
```

See also: [Using the [Embed] metadata tag](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=embed_3.html)

Comment: Thank you! And I found with this way I have to determine the width and height manually or the default width and height are 0...